# .htaccess redirect and get variables trouble

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have been working for some time to try and get

```
website.com/$1/$2/$3
website.com/$1/$2
```

to produce

```
website.com/public/index.php?module=$1&controller=$2&action=$3
website.com/public/index.php?controller=$1&action=$2
```

but I cannot seem to get it working

I am attempting this with two .htaccess files

.htaccess file located in root/

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes

   RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !^public/ public%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

 </IfModule>
```

.htaccess file located in root/public/

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes

   RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^public/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)(/|)$ public/index.php?module=$1&controller=$2&action=$3
RewriteRule ^public/([^/]+)/([^/]+)(/|)$ public/index.php?controller=$1&action=$2

 </IfModule>
```

I currently have it redirecting to the public/ but cannot find a way to change the get variables

Answer (score 1):

I solved it myself with this single .htaccess fine in the root

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L]
RewriteRule !^public/ public%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([style|css|js|javascript|images|img|fonts|swf]+)/(.*)$ public/$2/$3 [L]

RewriteRule ^public/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ public/index.php?module=$1&controller=$2&action=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^public/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ public/index.php?controller=$1&action=$2 [L]
```

EDIT:

I have chosen to move my url pacing to my php since htaccess is a nightmere for this sort of thing and If / Else statements are amazing... new code for those of you with similar problem is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([style|css|js|javascript|images|img|fonts|swf]+)/(.*)$ public/$2/$3 [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /error404
ErrorDocument 403 /error403
```

Answer (score 0):

In root/public/.htaccess, matched and rewrote pathes are relative to root/public, so they don't start with public, and you must not try to match ^public:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)(/|)$ index.php?module=$1&controller=$2&action=$3
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)(/|)$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2
```

The optional slash at the end can be matched with `/?`:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?module=$1&controller=$2&action=$3
```

Answer (score 0):

The Tag `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` only works in the apache-configuration.

In your .htaccess file you have to start with

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
```

followed by your conditions.

Comment: not true, <IfModule> works in .htaccess / directory context too